# awk - quick to way select rows without missing values

Tags: performance, awk, scripting

Given a csv-file, I need to skip lines with any empty fields. Number of fields `x` is fixed and known but large.

Using a simple `NF == x { commands }` fails as `NF` is counted on basis of the separators and their occurence reliable and independent from value occurence.

Looping over all fields on the other hand succeeds but seems to be a quite slow approach:

```
{
for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ ) {
    if ( $i == "" ) { next }
    else if ( i == NF ) { commands }
    }
}
```

Is there a quick and elegant way to select rows with no empty fields?

---

Note:

I am aware of `sed` or `grep` solutions searching for separators at the beginning/end of a line and two adjunct separators - it's part of a more complex `awk`-script.

---

Example file, lines 1 and 4 are to be selected:

```
11,12,13,14,15,16
21,22,,24,25,26
31,,33,34,35,36
41,42,43,44,45,46
,52,53,54,55,56
61,62,63,64,65,
```

Comment: `grep -v ',,\|^,\|,$' file` or with GNU sed: `sed -E '/(,,|^,|,$)/d' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or don't use field definitions

```
$ awk '!/(^|,)(,|$)/' file

11,12,13,14,15,16
41,42,43,44,45,46
```

which can be done with `sed` as well.

Comment: I like this as fields are still separated and can directly be processed further.